# How to count all files changed betwee two versions in a Github repository using Python

Tags: python, github-api

I am writting a python code able to count how many files have been changed between two versions of a repository. After several fails using GH APIs I opted for something like this: Read the HTML of the page user/repo/pagecomare/v1..v2 on github and look in the HTML for how many files have been changed (there is written: commits: .... and Files changed: ....) so very basic and not so smart, I guess.

When using APIS, this is what I tried:

```
def compare_versions(self, v1, v2, g, repo_name):  # NOT WORKING       
    
    try:
        repo = g.get_repo(repo_name)
        comparison = repo.compare(v1, v2)
        commits = comparison.total_commits
        print("Tot commits = ",commits)
        changed_files = comparison.files
        diff_files_url = comparison.diff_url
        print("Changed files: ", str(len(changed_files)))
        print("Diff files count: ", str(len(diff_files_url)))

    except BaseException as be:
        print(f"Base Exception occured for {v1} and {v2} = ", be)
```

The output is:

```
Base Exception occured for v25.0.5 and v26.0.0 =  404 {"message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/commits/commits#compare-two-commits"}
```

And this is the url I am using as Test:

```
https://github.com/apache/dubbo/compare/dubbo-3.1.10...dubbo-3.0.15
```

Any idea?

Comment: Would you be open to using git itself to do this?

Comment: You can use `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r v1..v2` and it will give you a list of all the files that have changed. Then you can count the lines with `wc -l` if you're on UNIX or `Measure-Object -line` if you're on PowerShell for Windows.

Comment: @TechnoSam I am open to use git itself, unfortunately never did it from terminal. Where do I specify the repo path in the command you posted?

Comment: First you would need to clone the repository to your computer.  You can change directories into the repo (`cd`) and then run this command. If this is something that you are doing very frequently on lots of different repos, the argument for using GH API is pretty strong. But if you just need it for one, this is definitely going to be easier.
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository

Comment: Note that you don't need to change directory to the target repository -- that's what the `git -C <directory>` option is for.

Comment: @TechnoSam I am using `Repo.clone()` function in python. So I `cd` into the directory and run the command: `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r dubbo-3.1.10..3.1.5
fatal: ambiguous argument 'dubbo-3.1.10..3.1.5': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: cloning from terminal and hittingt he command above prompts `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r dubbo-3.1.10..3.1.5
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did and solved the problem:

```
    def get_changed_files(self, repo_path, v1, v2):
        '''
        :param repo_path: part of the repo in form: owner/repo
        :param v1: first version to be compared
        :param v2: second version to be compared
        :return: number of files changed
        '''
        print(f"Getting number of changed files for repository {repo_path} and v1 = {v1}, v2 = {v2}")
        repo_info = repo_path.split("/")
        headers = {'Authorization': "Token " + self.access_token}
        url = f"https://github.com/{repo_info[0]}/{repo_info[1]}/compare/{v1}...{v2}.diff"
        #print("Comparing url = ", url)
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, auth=(self.api_username, self.access_token))
        except BaseException as be:
            print(f"Something went wrong when retrieving number of changed files between {v1} and {v2} "
                  f"for repository {repo_path} and the following exception was raised: {be}. "
                  f"This value is mandatory, exiting!")
            exit(1)
        diff = response.content
        count = diff.count(b"diff --git")   # count() uses byte, so "b" is needed
        #print("Count via diff file = ", count)
        return count
```

May not be the best solution but I haven't manage to implement others.

Any other advice/correction is very welcome.